# Cannot get glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am getting this error messages - cant load glyphicons... Why?

[image]

Below is the folder structure of my code

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you need to add woff and woff2 MIME types to your web.config or add them directly in your webserver config file

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Sorry I mistook your dark theme for visual studio and I thought you was using ASP.NET

I leave this code snippet because the same problem could be faced by ASP.NET users

Comment: Thank you !! Worked perfectly !!